# Trigger click Checkbox After page fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I run trigger click after page FULLY loaded

I have a checkbox and want to trigger a click.

my code is simple

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.wcpf-input-checkbox[value="hoodie"]').trigger('click');
});
```

but it does not work, I tes the script in console after fullu loaded, my script work

I also to try to check if the checkbox ready. it does not work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.wcpf-input-checkbox[value="hoodie"]').ready(function(){
    jQuery(this).click();
});

});
```

How do I trigger click to work?

Comment: Your code is right. Maybe your button is created at runtime? Or is the click action dynamically attached after your trigger?

Comment: @MichelaDurazzi that makes sense, because the list of checkboxes needs to get value from DB first and display. but when I try to add class it works. Maybe it's because the checkbox will be processed using ajax needs an actual click. how about it?

Comment: are you creating checkboxes dynamically? after the page load?

Answer (score 0):

If you attach click action with this method:

$(yourobj).on("click",function() {...});

then you can change it to:

$(document).on("click", 'yourobj', function(event) {...});

But I don't know, you haven't posted all of your code.

Answer (score -1):

The issue for me trigger clicks only can be run after the page fully loaded so I bind my code after window load() and set timeout

Here I solved it

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
     
        setTimeout(function(){
        //your code here
            console.log('All assets are loaded');
            jQuery('.wcpf-input-checkbox[value="hoodie"]').trigger('click');
            jQuery('.wcpf-button-action-filter').trigger('click');
        }, 1000);
    })
```